# add 30 days to a variable in sql then echo in php

Tags: php, date, time

Like an expiration date for a subscribed member.

May sound simple but all i get is the 31st january 1969!

eg.

```
<? $expire = strtotime("+30 days",$subscribed); echo $expire;?>
```

The SQL entry is already using the Y-M-D format and works fine when just echoed as a variable.

But when i try to add 30 days to the $subscribed value all i get is a bunch of numbers which when put through the .date function comes up with 31-01-1969

Probably an easy solution but i'm a noob lol.

Appreciate any help :)

Comment: you have some error , so only it showing up 31-01-1969

Comment: What is contained in the $subscribed variable, currently?

Answer (score 1):

you have to tell PHP that your string is a date and use the datetime object :

```
<?php
$date = new DateTime($subscribed);
$date->add(new DateInterval('P30D'));
$expire = $date->format('Y-m-d');
echo $expire;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$expire = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($subscribed. ' + 30 days'));
echo $expire;
```

read more about [strtotime](https://www.php.net/strtotime)

Answer (score 0):

The second parameter of [strtotime](https://www.php.net/strtotime) should be the timestamp used as a base for the calculation of relative dates

Try this.

```
$expire = date('Y-m-d', strtotime("+30 days", strtotime($subscribed)));
echo $expire;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use below code to add 30 days with your date

```
<?php
$expire = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($subscribed . " +30 days"));
echo $expire;
?>
```

Comment: Fantastic. worked like a charm. thanks for the help guys. i'm sure i'll be back :)